# How do we integrate $\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration

I would appreciate it if someone explained to me how to integrate

$$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\mathrm{d}x$$

For context, I am a physics major who is integrating an electric field expression for a straight line of charge, but I do not know the correct method to integrate such an expression.

Comment: If $x$ is strictly positive, then $x = \frac{a}{\sinh t}$ will do the trick.

Comment: Yes, the x in this case is defined as the positive distance along a coordinate axis. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Pull out an $x$ from the square root

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}}} = \int \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+a^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2}}\:d\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

From here the substitution becomes obvious

$$\frac{1}{x} = \frac{\sinh t}{a} \implies d\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{\cosh t}{a}\:dt$$

which means the integral is simply

$$\int \frac{-\cosh t}{a\cosh t}\:dt = -\frac{t}{a} + C = -\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You can either apply the substitution $x = a\sinh(u)$ or $x = a\tan(u)$. Let us stick with the first option:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}} = \frac{1}{a}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sinh(u)} = \frac{1}{a}\int\frac{\sinh(u)}{\sinh^{2}(u)}\mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{a}\int\frac{\sinh(u)}{\cosh^{2}(u) - 1}\mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}

Then you can apply the partial fraction method to the last integral.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: There is a more direct solution if you simplify the integrand first, have look at my answer

Comment: @NinadMunshi Nice solution! I will keep mine for the sake of curiosity.

Comment: Yes, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $I=\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\mathrm{d}x$; Substitute $x=a\tan \theta\implies dx=a\sec^2\theta d\theta$ so 
$I=\frac 1a \int \operatorname {cosec} \theta  d\theta=\frac 1a \ln|\tan \frac \theta 2|+c$ 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I see. Clever substitution. Could you share what intuition you used to find this substitution?

Comment: @bobbysacre: The idea was to remove square root in denominator and that $1+\tan ^2(x)=\sec^2 (x)$ trigonometric